# Grocery Crud not showing all items added

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

I have 'intervalosHorarios' and 'entregas' in my proyect, and when i clic on an 'intervaloHorario' it shows 'entregas' from that 'intervaloHorario'. The problem is to add more 'entregas' because it's showing only the fist one added. I wanna show all 'entregas' inside that 'intervaloHorario'. Any ideas?

**Tables**
[image]

**Controller**

```
public function entregas_lista($idCarga) {

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $datos = array(
            'title' => "entregas", // En la vista 'header' tendré una variable $title
            'username' => "Administrador"
        );

        $this->load->view('commons/header', $datos);

        //Quitamos los botones de añadir y quitar
        $crud->unset_add();
        $crud->unset_edit();

        $crud->set_language("spanish");
        $crud->set_theme('bootstrap');
        $crud->set_table('entregas');



        $crud->where('idCarga =', $idCarga);



        $crud->display_as('idCarga', 'Nº Entrega');
        $crud->set_subject('Carga / Descarga'); 
      $crud->set_relation('idIntervaloHorario', 'intervalosHorarios', 'intervaloHorario');

        $crud->columns('fechaCita', 'horaCita', 'numeroEntrega', 'cliente', 'Origen', 'Destino', 'cargaPrevista', 'entregaPrevista', 'accion', 'estado');




        $output = $crud->render();




        $this->_example_output($output);


        //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/footer.php'  ------------- /
        $this->load->view('commons/footer');
    }




    function _example_output($output = null) {
        $this->load->view('example', (array) $output);
    }
```

When I clic on 'De 12:00 a 13:30 it shows the same rows that 'De 7:00 a 8:30' link, and if i uncomment 'where' clause, it shows fine (the information of that link) but only with one row.

**Interval table**
[image]

**Delivery table**[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `$crud->where('idCarga =', $idCarga);` and I suppose that `$idCarga` is the PK of 'Entregas' table and PK's are unique. So it can be only one row for each PK.

EDIT: `$crud->where('entregas.idIntervaloHorario =', $idCarga);` to mach every row which has FK of 'IntervalosHorarios' table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but i'm still lost, what should i do? i'm new with grocery and php, please help.

Comment: Well, when you set where clause, in this case, `$crud->where()`, your database will search for a row where his `idCarga` is the same as your value set ($idCarga in this case). To avoid this, just remove that piece of code or just comment it and try again.

Comment: Yes, it works, but i think i didn't a well explanation. I just want to clic on 'intervalosHorarios' and show 'entregas' inside that 'intervalosHorarios', that's why i was using the were clause.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you want. Can you share a picture or smth of what you want?

Comment: I have added the new explanation and two images, they are at the end of the question. When I clic on 'De 12:00 a 13:30 it shows the same rows that 'De 7:00 a 8:30' link, and if i uncomment 'where' clause, it shows fine but only with one row.

Comment: Well, I suppose function 'entregas_lista' is called when you click a interval's table id right? So try to change where clause to  `$crud->where('idIntervaloHorario =', $idCarga);`

Comment: It throws: A Database Error Occurred:
Column 'idIntervaloHorario' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: `$crud->where('entregas.idIntervaloHorario =', $idCarga);` ?

Comment: Thank you very much!! that is what i was looking for! you are a crack! modify the question above, i will validate it